# The title of the secondary axis does not appear on the chart via vba

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am, new to VBA and I am making a chart that needs to have two y axes and share the same x axis. I am not very sure about the whole concept of xlvalue and xlcategory and how to use them and I used some of the examples online but I cant make it work. I have pasted my code below. Thanks in advance !!

```
With Totalchart.Axes(xlCategory)
    .HasTitle = True
    .HasTitle = True
    .HasMajorGridlines = True
    .HasMinorGridlines = True
    With .AxisTitle
        .Caption = "Time (min)"
        .Font.Name = "bookman"
        .Font.Size = 10
    End With
End With

With Totalchart.Axes(xlValue)
    '.CategoryType = xlAutomatic
    .HasTitle = True
    .HasTitle = True
    .HasMajorGridlines = True
    .HasMinorGridlines = True
    .MinimumScale = 0
    With .AxisTitle
        .Caption = "caption1"
        .Font.Name = "bookman"
        .Font.Size = 10
    End With
End With

With Totalchart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary)
    '.CategoryType = xlAutomatic
    .HasTitle = True
    .HasTitle = True
    .MinimumScale = 0
    With .AxisTitle
        .Caption = "Caption2"
        .Font.Name = "bookman"
        .Font.Size = 10
    End With
End With
```

Comment: In general `xlValue` is y axis and `xlCategory` is x axis

Answer (score 0):

`.AxisTitle.Text` and `.AxisTitle.Caption` are slightly different.  See this [MSDN Documention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb255847%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

In Excel 2007 set the `.AxisTitle.Text` to your axis title like this:

```
With Totalchart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary)
    .HasTitle = True
    .MinimumScale = 0
    With .AxisTitle
        .Text = "Axis Title"
        .Font.Name = "bookman"
        .Font.Size = 10
    End With
End With
```

---

Make sure you have secondary axis enabled before this code. Something like this depending on your seriescollection.

```
With Totalchart
  .SeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = xlSecondary
  .HasAxis(xlValue, xlSecondary) = True
  .Axes(xlCategory, xlSecondary).CategoryType = xlAutomatic
End With
```

---

Also, try recording a macro of yourself manually creating the secondary axis and investigate the code.  Might help with your naming.

Comment: I am using Excel 2007. The code you wrote (for the last block) gives me the following error:
method 'setElement' of object '_Chart' failed

Comment: I get the "Method 'axes' of object '_Chart' failed" for 'With Totalchart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary)' line

Comment: See update, make sure you have enabled the secondary axis first.